# Angular: how to put application state on route params (url)?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

how can we put "http://localhost:4200/#/{"page":"product", "shoe":"47372", "isOpen":false} " on url so that when the user share the link, the other end could construct the state using it
using angular spa with ngrx

Edited One,

the question is not how to pars params but how to put in the params of the active route.

Comment: you can set the values as query params., you are probably getting downvoted due to not showing what you tried. And it looks like you are trying to share localhost link which clearly wont work. you can set it by modify location or navigating setting query params, and retreive by using activatedRoute and get queryParams.

Answer (score 0):

you should use params

just like http://localhost:4200/#/?page=product&shoe=47372&isOpen=false

and use `this.router.params` to get the params

```
this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.page = params['page'];
      // ....
    });
```

Comment: The OP is asking about how to set URL parameters, this answer is more focused on how to read them

Answer (score 0):

First, a quick suggestion to ensure that the problem you're trying to solve here is the problem you should solve.

It's generally good to decouple the state from the path as much as possible. For the most part, I think of "state" as recording a set of interactions within a page (e.g. the things that a user does *after* already being on the shoe #47372 product page).

So you might rather organizing around routes rather than route parameters.

- If "product" is supposed to be a page, make it a page: "/#/product"
- Looking at shoes? "/#/product/shoe"
- Looking at shoe #47372? "/#/product/shoe/47372"

Whatever `isOpen` is supposed to do might work best as a query parameter, though, which `RouterLink` can do!

---

That said, Angular's [RouterLink directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) provides multiple options for parameterizing our routes. It's probably simplest to use `queryParams` to add query parameters:

```
<a routerLink="/my/path" [queryParams]="{ foo: 'bar', foo2: 'bar2' }">My Router Link</a>
```

Yields a router link with this path: `/my/path?foo=bar&foo2=bar2`.

---

But if you want to organize your route hierarchy differently, you can pass an array to `routerLink`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['my', 'path', myParam]">My Router Link</a>
```

Where your component has a public member `myParam` (let's say it's set to `"foo"`).
This would yield a router link with this path: `/my/path/foo` (b/c the value of `myParam` is "foo").